Match output of a CURL in an IF-ELSE condition in BASH

I want to evaluate the output of a curl in an if-else.
If the first condition matches, then shell return 0 and hence I equate to zero.
Similarly for the second condition
If Nothing matches go to else block

I have the following
if [[ curl https://www.example.com | grep -q "Match 1 Found" = 0 ]]
then
    echo "Match 1 Found"
elif [[ curl https://www.example.com | grep -q "Match 2 Found" = 0 ]]
then
    echo "Match 2 Found"
else
    echo "No Match Found"

PS : I am equating to zero since shell returns 0 if it is True

Possible duplicates: "Checking the success of a command in a bash if [ .. ] statement", "Bash conditional based on exit code of command", and "When are square brackets required in a Bash if statement?"

[[ ]] is used to evaluate conditional expressions, but you don't need that when testing a command. The exit status of a command is tested directly by if.
So just write:
if curl https://www.example.com | grep -q "Match 1 Found"

If you're doing the same curl in both if and elif, you probably should save the output in a variable rather than going to the website twice.
results=$(curl https://www.example.com)
case "$result" in
    *"Match 1 Found"*) echo "Match 1 Found" ;;
    *"Match 2 Found"*) echo "Match 2 Found" ;;
    *) echo "No Match Found" ;;
esac

